# Issue with using $inc express route with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to subtract a value from my quantities on my database.  I am not getting any errors but it's not subtracting the values.  I can run this in mongo shell and it works so I am not sure what I am missing here.

```
router.post("/item/:id", middleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  Item.findById(req.params.id, (err, item) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    var soldItem = {
      id: item._id,
      item: item.name,
      askPrice: item.price
    };
    var soldPrice = req.body.soldPrice;
    var soldQuantity = req.body.soldQuantity;
    var itemSold = {
      soldItem: soldItem,
      soldPrice: soldPrice,
      soldQuantity: soldQuantity
    };
    SoldItem.create(itemSold, (err, sold) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        item.solditems = item.solditems || []; // if solditems undefined set to empty array
        item.solditems.push(sold);
        item.save().then(() => {
          item.udpdate({
            $inc: { quantity: parseInt(soldQuantity) * -1 }
          });
        });

        req.flash("success", "Item Sold");
        res.redirect("/products");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What did you run in the `mongo` shell that works? Could you post that code here?

Comment: db.items.update({name: "Test Item 1"}, {$inc: {quantity: -4}})

Comment: I wrote that and it worked ... I dont want to subtract -4 every time I want whatever the user inputs in the form to subtract the quantity

Comment: Could you debug the code and ensure that `soldQuantity` is not zero when you hit the `item.update`?

Comment: Ok so I tried console.log(soldQuantity) and nothing shows up ... not even 0.  I was trying to pull from that variable because it was set with req.body.soldQuantity.  The database shows the correct amount entered but for some reason I cant get it to update the total

Comment: `req.body.soldQuantity` is a "string". Mongoose casts that "normally" as a "separate value" but the JavaScript operation wont do that. You need `{ $inc: { quantity: parseInt(soldQuantity) * -1 } }` in order to make the expression valid.

Comment: Also the usage of `update()` in this context is incorrect. `SoldItem.update()` uses the "query" as the first argument. `item.update()` which is actually the "instance" from the initial `.findById()` does not use the "query" as the first argument as it's "implied" to simply be issued using the `_id` from the returned instance. So it's only `item.udpdate({ $inc: { quantity: parseInt(soldQuantity) * -1 } })` . But the whole structure makes it unclear what you are really trying to do as the `async` here is useless and not doing what you seem to think it's doing.

Comment: You would be better off here showing the current document(s) state and what you expect to achieve from your code. Then we can point you in the right direction, since there's more than a few problems with the current code.

Comment: I tried that as well earlier and it didn't work either. That's why I removed it.  I put it back just to test and it's still not working.  Like I said, I can try to console.log(soldItem)  anywhere in the async block and it doesnt even return anything.

Comment: So what are you wanting to see?

Comment: @Darrell You need to use the `@` "thingy" when addressing people in comment responses. We don't actually get notified of your comment unless you do that. See my comment here as the example of how you do that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of problems with the code here, but as best as I can figure out then what you actually want to do is this:

```
// note that "async" is here because inner methods use "await"
router.post("/item/:id", middleware.isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {

  try {
    let item = await Item.findById(req.params.id);

    // Do casting manually because you really want to
    let soldPrice = parseFloat(req.body.soldPrice);
    let soldQuantity = parseInt(req.body.soldQuantity);

    let soldItem = {
      id: item._id,
      item: item.name,
      askPrice: item.price
    };

    // create the sold item
    let soldItem = await SoldItem.create({
      soldItem,
      soldPrice,
      soldQuantity
    });

    // update the item
    await item.update({ "$inc": { "quantity": (soldQuantity * -1) } });

    // Then respond
    req.flash("success", "Item Sold");
    res.redirect("/products");
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("err", err.stack);
   // really should send the error on res here as well
  }
})
```

Or if you don't actually have `async/await` support in your node version, then with plain Promises:

```
router.post("/item/:id", middleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {

  // Do casting manually because you really want to
  let soldPrice = parseFloat(req.body.soldPrice);
  let soldQuantity = parseInt(req.body.soldQuantity);

  Item.findById(req.params.id).then(item =>
    SoldItem.create({
      soldItem: {
        id: item._id,
        item: item.name,
        askPrice: item.price
      },
      soldPrice,
      soldQuantity
    })
    .then(() => item.update({ "$inc": { "quantity": (soldQuantity * -1) }));
  }).then(() => {
    // Then respond
    req.flash("success", "Item Sold");
    res.redirect("/products");
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log("err", err.stack);
    // really should send the error on res here as well
  });
})
```

So the two "main" issues in the code are that the value in `req.body.soldQuantity` is actually a "string". When you send such values through something like `SoldItem.create()` then mongoose uses the "schema" to cast the values into whatever is defined in the schema. In your case that would be `Number`.

JavaScript will take a "reasonable guess" with the later `soldQuantity *-1` statement and "cast" for you, but really you should be aware of such things and simply do the type conversion in the code "explicitly" rather than relying on the implicit casting.

The next problem was the invocation of `update()`. There are "two forms" of this available to mongoose, being [`Model.update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#update_update) and [`Document.update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update). The former applies a "query" condition as in:

```
await Model.update({ "_id": 1 },{ "$inc": { "rounds": 1 } })`
```

The `Document` or "instance" version works with an "already retrieved" document and has a different syntax:

```
let document = await Model.findById(1);
await document.update({ "$inc": { "rounds": 1 } });
```

Since you already did `Item.findById()`, then the returned "document" is used for that form of `update()` in a way which basically "implies":

```
await Item.update(
  { "_id": item._id },       // this is implied from the "instance"
  { "$inc": { "quantity": (soldQuantity * -1) } }
);
```

But of course written in the "shorter" form "without the query" portion as is demonstrated in the code.

The rest really comes down to misunderstanding the mix of Promises and "callback" handling and the purpose of the `async/await` keywords and how they translate to the standard promise handling. But the code given should hopefully set those misconceptions straight now you have an example to follow.

Comment: Man you have been a big help with this project and I cant thank you enough.  I know I have a lot to learn still.  Other than the docs for things like mongo and express and so on do you have any thoughts on good resources for learning?

Comment: BTW I tried using the @ with your name it it disappeared... Not sure if it's supposed to do that

Comment: @Darrell You don't need to do that when commenting on "my" answer because messages to "me" are "implied". It matters when responding to comments on "your" question. Lots of resources out there, and of course you can always search for anything that comes up for existing answers here.